# IIS7/Win7 - Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path

Tags: authentication, iis-7, windows-7

I am running a localhost instance (so domains are not my issue!) on my laptop utilizing Win7 and IIS7.  I am getting authentication errors on my website and my one virtual directory.

```
default website - localhost:80  c:\mydirectory\localhost
virtual directory - c:\mydirectory\weborb30
```

Please notice these are not under c:\inetpub\wwwroot!

Now, I did some googling/binging and discovered that I needed to add my [machinename$] to the ACLs.  (Hope I said that right.)  I did that, even though it is a domain thing.  Nothing changed.  I further read that IIS7 is now using ApplicationPoolIdentity and I tried finding that on my local machine - no luck there.  So, I changed the App Pool to run under another built in account.  Now, not only do I get the Authentication error I can no longer AttachProcess to W3WP.

How the heck do you **PROPERLY** setup VS2005, IIS7 on a WIN7 box to run locally???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you made changes to the app pools, all you probably needed to do was add read access to your physical directory for the "network service" account (that is the default account used by asp.net on vista & win7).

I think what you may be looking for at this point is this:

```
aspnet_regiis -ga <useraccount>
```

The -ga switch tells aspnet_regiis to configure all the security for asp.net. Usually you only need to do this stuff when you are using impersonation in your application, but if you are changing the default user for the application pools then you are effectivly doing the same thing IIS wide.

The best complete [documentation I've found is on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998297.aspx). It applies to the previous version of IIS, IIS 6, but it is pretty easy to apply it in IIS 7 environments

Comment: thanks.  Managed to struggle through it before I saw this.  Just have some minor issues with WebOrb that I am working through.  WebOrb will create temp directories and those will sometimes pop a security error.  (sigh)

Answer (score 9):

I was having a similar problem and ended up fixing it by giving read permissions to the "IUSR" user and "IIS_IUSRS" group.

I'm not really sure why this works. It seems odd needing to give permissions to IUSR when I thought it would have been included in the IIS_IUSRS group. I think part of it relates to the account the application pool runs as (e.g. "IIS AppPool\Classic .NET AppPool" for a classic .NET application pool in IIS 7.5 / Windows 7), but I'm still unclear.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271913/iis-7-5-mvc-requires-authentication-to-get-static-files) StackOverflow question seems to be related.

Comment: crazy..... I had the group set up w rights... and just like you, had to give explicit rights to IUSR....  crazy! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to restart the IIS here: [IIS Location to restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YIhm.png) and don't use  iisreset etc

if that doesn't work try to add it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63y1Y.png) first, and then Restart (right click again and restart through the interface.) then get it back to the correct permissions.. Restart again in the same way.

I hope it helps it solve most of the bugs for me in that subject..